# ENOMEM in NodeJS and Lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am running an image processing service that uses Node Canvas, rsvg, and libvips to rendering and transform images.  Currently, the system runs fine, but after extended usage I begin to see ENOMEM errors thrown.

**Background**

Notes on system setup:

- Node version is 12
- Lambda has 4096MB RAM
- The Lambda is passing `--max-old-space-size=3687` and `--max-semi-space-size=204` (I don't seem to be able to configure this)

According to [this](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/25382) issue there are problems with the way spawn and exec work with memory.  From my understanding, once > 50% of Nodes memory is in use calls to exec or spawn will fails as they attempt to allocate > 100% of the remaining memory.

Logging some data from the running Lambda, I can see that the system has the following:

```
os.totalmem() // 5789110272
os.freemem() // 3055075328

process.memoryUsage() 
/*
{
  "rss": 2521698304,
  "heapTotal": 62386176,
  "heapUsed": 58013056,
  "external": 38297409,
  "arrayBuffers": 36799944
}
*/
```

Final log from the Lambda:

```
Duration: 109.00 ms Billed Duration: 110 ms Memory Size: 4096 MB Max Memory Used: 2458 MB
```

In this specific example, `ENOMEM` was thrown while trying to `spawn` and run the `fc-cache` command.  This execution context is being re-used, as this call is the first call made before any major processing happens.

**Problem**

How do I approach debugging and resolving this issue?  Im not sure which tooling I should be using, since this is also on Lambda.

I'm aware there's a memory leak, but I'm not sure if it's my code that's causing it or something like [this](https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/issues/1974) issue.  My code is incredibly simple, but I am using several dependencies that I haven't looked through (Sentry, axios, nodecanvas, etc).

Comment: The lambda will need available memory the size of the `node` process to complete the spawn.

Comment: Does `fc-cache` need to be run repeatedly? It seems like something that could be done in a container build outside of the node context.

Comment: Otherwise allocate 2x the node memory, or change the parent of the fc-cache process.

Comment: Thanks for your comment!  I believe I've resolved the problem which ended up being something else, but wanted to answer your questions anyways.  I noticed Canvas would sometimes "miss" and not render the correct font, but I will test removing fc-cache now that I've sorted out this issue.  However, increasing Lambda memory does not help, as the issue ultimately was a memory leak.  As soon as the Node process hit > 50% memory usage, calls to spawn would throw ENOMEM.

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

After re-reading my own post and doing some additional research, it dawned on me that Node Canvas was not being cleaned up properly.  I'm not sure how I overlooked this first, since the reported pango/cairo memory leak is so much slower than what I was seeing in my app.

The fact that ENOMEM was being thrown by calls to `exec` and `spawn` was just a symptom of this problem.  The root problem was that repeated usage of NodeCanvas was holding onto memory.  Once process memory hit > 50%, spawn calls would fail due to the NodeJS bug I highlighted above.

The post that ultimately helped me solve the problem is [this](https://promincproductions.com/blog/node-js-fabric-js-memory-leaks-prevent-enomem/).  Note: I'm also using `fabricjs`, which may have also been partially responsible.

```
canvas.clear()
canvas.dispose()
canvas.interactive && canvas.removeListeners()
```

After implementing this, the memory growth is much slower, so much so that the Lambda container is removed before the increase ever becomes an issue.